# gulp-ruby-sass @import while compiling a unique file

Tags: css, ruby, import, sass, gulp

I am using Gulp with gulp-ruby-sass to compile scss files. The project's folder looks like:

```
css/
    scss/
        grid.scss
        styles.scss
    styles.css
node_modules/
    .bin/
        ...
    gulp/
        ...
    gulp-ruby-sass/
        ...
gulpfile.js
index.html
```

gulpfile.js :

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
    sass = require( 'gulp-ruby-sass' );

// Styles
gulp.task( 'styles', function () {
  return gulp.src( 'css/scss/styles.scss' )
    .pipe( sass( { style : 'compressed' } ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'css/' ) );
});
```

css/scss/styles.scss:

```
@import 'grid';
```

css/styles.css trace the error "File to import not found or unreadable: grid".

The documentation recommends to include all required .scss file in the `gulp.dest()` glob so did I:

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
    sass = require( 'gulp-ruby-sass' );

// Styles
gulp.task( 'styles', function () {
  return gulp.src( 'css/scss/*.scss' )
    .pipe( sass( { style : 'compressed' } ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'css/' ) );
});
```

It works perfectly fine now but every `.scss` files are compiled and exported as `.css` files while I just want the `styles.scss` file to be exported as `styles.css`.

How could I do it? Should I stick with every files being exported?

---

**EDIT:** I made several attempts using "loadPath" but the path seems to be relative to the gulp-ruby-sass folder and not the project:

`/private/var/folders/tb/tlvf2ysj21x49qb1h3fgbjz00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use scss partials naming convention, this is, start with an underscore (_), so you tell Sass that files must not be compiled itself.

Rename grid.scss to _grid.scss

styles.scss stays since you want it compiled.

Import as `@import 'grid'`;

Comment: Yes, it will, but it will also compile files that dont't start with "_" (underscore), and thats exactly what he is asking on his edit. Please, considere removing the negative vote.

Comment: @cimmanon actually avcajaraville is right, his answer solved my problem. Thank you! :)